# Azure - ARM deployment of Cosmos DB for Mongo fails with "x-ms-cosmos-migrate-offer-to-manual-throughput must be supplied" error

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cosmosdb, azure-rm-template, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I am trying to deploy a new Azure Cosmos DB for Mongo DB account with two collections, one of them has autoscale throughput whereas the other has manual throughput. I am deploying the ARM template via a powershell script and the `New-AzResourceGroupDeployment` command. However, this fails with the error:

```
Status Message: Message: {"code":"BadRequest","message":"Message: 
{\"Errors\":[\"x-ms-cosmos-migrate-offer-to-manual-throughput must be supplied and offercontent 
must contain autopilotSettings for migration of autoscale collection to manual throughput.\"]}
```

The strange part is that the Cosmos DB resource is actually deployed perfectly fine with all the settings as I defined them. At no point in the ARM template am I attempting to migrate to manual throughput.

This is the ARM template for the cosmos db

```
   {
      "type": "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts",
      "apiVersion": "2023-04-15",
      "name": "[variables('provisionedCosmosAccountName')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "kind": "MongoDB",
      "properties": {
        "databaseAccountOfferType": "Standard",
        "minimalTlsVersion": "Tls12",
        "consistencyPolicy": {
          "defaultConsistencyLevel": "Session",
          "maxIntervalInSeconds": 5,
          "maxStalenessPrefix": 100
        },
        "apiProperties": {
          "serverVersion": "4.2"
        },
        "locations": [
          {
            "locationName": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "failoverPriority": 0,
            "isZoneRedundant": false
          }
        ],
        "capabilities": [
          {
            "name": "EnableMongo"
          },
          {
            "name": "DisableRateLimitingResponses"
          }
        ],
        "backupPolicy": {
          "type": "Periodic",
          "periodicModeProperties": {
            "backupIntervalInMinutes": 240,
            "backupRetentionIntervalInHours": 8,
            "backupStorageRedundancy": "Geo"
          }
        },
        "capacity": {
          "totalThroughputLimit": 7000
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/mongodbDatabases",
      "apiVersion": "2023-04-15",
      "name": "[format('{0}/{1}', variables('provisionedCosmosAccountName'), variables('cosmosDatabaseName'))]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts', variables('provisionedCosmosAccountName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "resource": {
          "id": "[variables('cosmosDatabaseName')]"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/mongodbDatabases/collections",
      "apiVersion": "2023-04-15",
      "name": "[format('{0}/{1}/{2}', variables('provisionedCosmosAccountName'), variables('cosmosDatabaseName'), 'Audits')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/mongodbDatabases', variables('provisionedCosmosAccountName'), variables('cosmosDatabaseName'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts', variables('provisionedCosmosAccountName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "resource": {
          "id": "Audits",
          "shardKey": {
            "PartitionKey": "Hash"
          },
          "indexes": [
            {
              "key": {
                "keys": [
                  "_id"
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "key": {
                "keys": [
                  "PartitionKey"
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/mongodbDatabases/collections",
      "apiVersion": "2023-04-15",
      "name": "[format('{0}/{1}/{2}', variables('provisionedCosmosAccountName'), variables('cosmosDatabaseName'), 'Event')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/mongodbDatabases', variables('provisionedCosmosAccountName'), variables('cosmosDatabaseName'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts', variables('provisionedCosmosAccountName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "resource": {
          "id": "Event",
          "shardKey": {
            "PartitionKey": "Hash"
          },
          "indexes": [
            {
              "key": {
                "keys": [
                  "_id"
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "key": {
                "keys": [
                  "PartitionKey",
                  "RunId"
                ]
              },
              "options": {
                "unique": true
              }
            },
            {
              "key": {
                "keys": [
                  "PartitionKey"
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "key": {
                "keys": [
                  "ChainId"
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "key": {
                "keys": [
                  "ActionCount"
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "key": {
                "keys": [
                  "EventId"
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "key": {
                "keys": [
                  "RunId"
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "options": {
          "autoscaleSettings": {
            "maxThroughput": 2000
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/mongodbDatabases/collections/throughputSettings",
      "apiVersion": "2023-04-15",
      "name": "[format('{0}/{1}/{2}', variables('provisionedCosmosAccountName'), variables('cosmosDatabaseName'), 'Audits/default')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/mongodbDatabases/collections', variables('provisionedCosmosAccountName'), variables('cosmosDatabaseName'), 'Audits')]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/mongodbDatabases', variables('provisionedCosmosAccountName'), variables('cosmosDatabaseName'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts', variables('provisionedCosmosAccountName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "resource": {
          "throughput": 500
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/mongodbDatabases/collections/throughputSettings",
      "apiVersion": "2023-04-15",
      "name": "[format('{0}/{1}/{2}', variables('provisionedCosmosAccountName'), variables('cosmosDatabaseName'), 'Event/default')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/mongodbDatabases/collections', variables('provisionedCosmosAccountName'), variables('cosmosDatabaseName'), 'Event')]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/mongodbDatabases', variables('provisionedCosmosAccountName'), variables('cosmosDatabaseName'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts', variables('provisionedCosmosAccountName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "resource": {
          "throughput": 200,
          "autoscaleSettings": {
            "maxThroughput": 2000
          }
        }
      }
    },
```

So far i've tried setting the autoscale limit for the database too with

```
"options": {
          "autoscaleSettings": {
            "maxThroughput": 7000
          }
        }
```

and i've also replaced the `capacity` and `totalThroughputLimit` setting in the `databaseAccounts` resource with

```
"options": {
          "autoscaleSettings": {
            "maxThroughput": 7000
          }
        }
```

Any ideas? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can't deploy new resources this way. You have a combination of a throughput resource for a collection defined in the options for the collection and two other throughput resources. You can only define new collections with throughput in the options. You also have defined both standard and autoscale throughput which is generating the throughput migration error.

This is the corrected ARM template.

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"variables": {
    "provisionedCosmosAccountName": "value",
    "cosmosDatabaseName": "value"
},
"resources": 
[
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts",
      "apiVersion": "2023-04-15",
      "name": "[variables('provisionedCosmosAccountName')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "kind": "MongoDB",
      "properties": {
        "databaseAccountOfferType": "Standard",
        "minimalTlsVersion": "Tls12",
        "consistencyPolicy": {
          "defaultConsistencyLevel": "Session",
          "maxIntervalInSeconds": 5,
          "maxStalenessPrefix": 100
        },
        "apiProperties": {
          "serverVersion": "4.2"
        },
        "locations": [
          {
            "locationName": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "failoverPriority": 0,
            "isZoneRedundant": false
          }
        ],
        "capabilities": [
          {
            "name": "EnableMongo"
          },
          {
            "name": "DisableRateLimitingResponses"
          }
        ],
        "backupPolicy": {
          "type": "Periodic",
          "periodicModeProperties": {
            "backupIntervalInMinutes": 240,
            "backupRetentionIntervalInHours": 8,
            "backupStorageRedundancy": "Geo"
          }
        },
        "capacity": {
          "totalThroughputLimit": 7000
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/mongodbDatabases",
      "apiVersion": "2023-04-15",
      "name": "[format('{0}/{1}', variables('provisionedCosmosAccountName'), variables('cosmosDatabaseName'))]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts', variables('provisionedCosmosAccountName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "resource": {
          "id": "[variables('cosmosDatabaseName')]"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/mongodbDatabases/collections",
      "apiVersion": "2023-04-15",
      "name": "[format('{0}/{1}/{2}', variables('provisionedCosmosAccountName'), variables('cosmosDatabaseName'), 'Audits')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/mongodbDatabases', variables('provisionedCosmosAccountName'), variables('cosmosDatabaseName'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts', variables('provisionedCosmosAccountName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "resource": {
          "id": "Audits",
          "shardKey": {
            "PartitionKey": "Hash"
          },
          "indexes": [
            {
              "key": {
                "keys": [
                  "_id"
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "key": {
                "keys": [
                  "PartitionKey"
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "options":{
            "throughput": 500
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/mongodbDatabases/collections",
      "apiVersion": "2023-04-15",
      "name": "[format('{0}/{1}/{2}', variables('provisionedCosmosAccountName'), variables('cosmosDatabaseName'), 'Event')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/mongodbDatabases', variables('provisionedCosmosAccountName'), variables('cosmosDatabaseName'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts', variables('provisionedCosmosAccountName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "resource": {
          "id": "Event",
          "shardKey": {
            "PartitionKey": "Hash"
          },
          "indexes": [
            {
              "key": {
                "keys": [
                  "_id"
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "key": {
                "keys": [
                  "PartitionKey",
                  "RunId"
                ]
              },
              "options": {
                "unique": true
              }
            },
            {
              "key": {
                "keys": [
                  "PartitionKey"
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "key": {
                "keys": [
                  "ChainId"
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "key": {
                "keys": [
                  "ActionCount"
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "key": {
                "keys": [
                  "EventId"
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "key": {
                "keys": [
                  "RunId"
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "options": {
          "autoscaleSettings": {
            "maxThroughput": 2000
          }
        }
      }
    }
]
}
```